# Static and final

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile this code

```
public class Foo {
    static final int x = 18;

    public void go(final int y){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public class Mixed2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

         Foo f = new Foo();
        f.go(11);
    }
}
```

And it is compiled. And even gives the result (18)
But this does not have to be. Why is this happening?
I use the idea
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "But this does not have to be"? It's printing out the value of the constant, which is 18. Why would you expect anything else? It's really unclear which aspect is confusing you, and what you were expecting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you wonder why the code is valid in the following cases, when you expect it to throw an error.

In this case, you are not changing the field `x`, but simply adding a new variable with the same name, that override (*shadows*) the field `x`:

```
public class Foo {
    static final int x = 18; // field x

    // This creates a new variable x which hides the field x above
    public void go(final int x /* variable x */) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

In these next two cases, you are trying to change `x`, which will result in an error:

```
public class Foo {
    static final int x = 18; // field x

    // The field x is final and cannot be changed.
    public void go() {
        x += 1;
    }
}

public class Foo {
    static final int x = 18; // field x

    // The variable x is final and cannot be changed.
    public void go(final int x /* variable x */) {
        x += 1;
    }
}
```

**Old Answer**: If you're trying to have it print `11`, you should call `System.out.println(y)` instead of using `x`.

Try following some Java tutorials and look closely at the code and at variable names.

Comment: I am not try compile this. On the contrary, I thought it should not be compiled. But code "public void go(final int x){ ... }" is compile too. But this is an attempt to change the constant and should cause an exception. Is not it so?

Comment: @YeroSun When you make `final int x` an argument to the function, it introduces a new variable that hides the field `static final int x` (it _shadows_ it). If you want there to be an error, you need to try assigning `x` inside `go`, but creating any other variable `x` than the field that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, **You cannot change the value of a final**... However, you are not changing any final numbers, and if you were, you would get compiler errors, not exceptions.

It is important to know the differences between static and final:

- Static makes a variable the same between all classes- Changing `go()` to static will still allow you to access it, but making `go()` static and removing static from `x` will prevent you from referencing `x`, because the `go()` function does not know which `Foo` class to find `x` in.
- Final Makes a variable unchangeable- I do not know of any performance reasons for this, but mostly for constants.

  - For example, you do not want to be able to set the value of Boolean.TRUE to false

---

```
public class Foo {
    static final int x = 18;

    public void go(final int y) {

        // This is not possible because 'x' is final,
        // however the state of 'y' does not matter,
        // because its value is not being changed
        x = y;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public class Mixed2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

         Foo f = new Foo();
        f.go(11);
    }
}
```